# R studio will not remember my file path for a code chunk

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run the following code I get an error.

```
library(tidyverse)
day <- read.csv("day.csv")[, -1]

glimpse(day)
```

Result:
Show in New Window
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

However when I specify the file path it works:

```
library(tidyverse)
setwd("~/UofUProjects/IS6489")
day <- read.csv("day.csv")[, -1]

glimpse(day)
```

I don't want to have to specify the file path for every single code chunk I run. Is this a setting I may have accidentally disabled? I tried deleting an re adding the file. I also tried clicking more and choosing set working directory and I still get the same error. I also tried updating Rstudio and R to the newest versions.

here is my working directory

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you run getwd() before running setwd()? Are you trying to knit a .rmd file? If so is it in the same folder as your data?

Comment: You have to run `setwd` command only once and not every time you read the file. The file should be present in your working directory if you don't want to use the complete path everytime.

Comment: The reason I think I will have to run it every time is I get this message after I run it: The working directory will be reset when the chunk is finished running. Use the knitr root.dir option in the setup chunk to change the working directory for notebook chunks.> day <- read.csv("day.csv")[, -1]

Comment: When I try get WD it shows my downloads folder instead of my workspace folder?

Answer (score 1):

The R markdown file I was using was saved in my download folder instead of my project folder. I was trying to specify the working directory folder with the R studio settings, and thought it would recognize however it did not work unless I actually saved the R markdown file in the project folder or used setwd(). I ran the code without the setwd() after I saved in the correct location and it worked just the way I wanted it to.